# How do I convert this html file into a web2py layout file?

Tags: layout, web2py

http://ideone.com/g9gdkK

According to the documentation, I have to change the hrefs and srcs to the URL form (after moving the files to static folder) and add {{include}} to the body, but the output is not proper.

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
  <link href="{{=URL('static', 'css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The original html code is in the link above.

Please help.

Comment: See the file `layout.html` and `default\index.html`. They give a good insight on how to set up the HTML

Comment: My file opens through the web2py interface. It's just that the formatting has not remained. And yes, I have gone though the layout file. I don't know how to use the {{include}}, I think. I just put it as the first line of the body.

Answer (score 1):

The file `views/layout.html` defines the overall structure of your site.

Find `{{include}}` - at this point the views (or the HTML code in your views) is included into the overall structure.

If you have a controller `test` and the function `output` as in `http:\\www.whatever.com\test\output`

```
def output():
    # Do something
    return dict(...)
```

Web2py is looking for a corresponding view `output.html` in `views/test` where you can do stuff with the returned contents (if you want to).

This HTML file might look like:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<div>
    <!-- Your contents -->
</div>
```

More informations regarding this topic can be found in the [page-layout section of the official documentation](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Page-layout).

Comment: I am unable to get the formatting to carry over from the normal HTML to the integrated into web2py one. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean your page LOOKS different (= different CSS) or the structure is messed up? Would be good if you could post screenshots of the two different states.

Comment: If you used Twitter Bootstrap please note that the default-Bootstrap used by web2py does look different!